# Is this number a power of two?

Tags: algorithm, binary

I have a number (in base 10) represented as a string with up to 10^6 digits. I want to check if this number is a power of two. One thing I can think of is binary search on exponents and using FFT and fast exponentiation algorithm, but it is quite long and complex to code. Let n denote the length of the input (i.e., the number of decimal digits in the input). What's the most efficient algorithm for solving this problem, as a function of n?

Comment: Which Language you are using?

Comment: C++, but writing own arithmetics is not a problem.

Comment: If Complexity is not problem then you can simply iterate through String and divide it by 2 and at last if you are left with 1 then number is a number of power two.

Comment: There are a lot of necessary (but not sufficient) conditions that are easy to check. For example testing if the last digit is even will eliminate 50% of the numbers.

Comment: Well, as you may see, my solutions contains Fast Fourier Transform and few other sophisticated algorithms, so complexity is a problem. It is not a basic programming question.

Comment: do you know the length in advance, or is it more like a stream that ideally should only be traversed once and you don't know when it's going to end?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/64534/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40004453/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Your question is too vague -- "Is there any other way?" is too open-ended (of course there are many other ways, but you probably won't be happy with most of them). Please edit to clarify your requirements.  Also, please edit the question to show us what approaches you've considered and why you've rejected them; then update the requirements to make sure that the reasons you rejected them are listed among the requirements; then show us the best approach you've found so far.

Answer (score 3):

There are either two or three powers of 2 for any given size of a decimal number, and it is easy to guess what they are, since the size of the decimal number is a good approximation of its base 10 logarithm, and you can compute the base 2 logarithm by just multiplying by an appropriate constant (log<sub>2</sub>10). So a binary search would be inefficient and unnecessary.

Once you have a trial exponent, which will be on the order of three million, you can use the squaring exponentiation algorithm with about 22 bugnum decimal multiplications. (And up to 21 doublings, but those are relatively easy.)

Depending on how often you do this check, you might want to invest in fast bignum code. But if it is infrequent, simple multiplication should be ok.

If you don't expect the numbers to be powers of 2, you could first do a quick computation mod 10<sup>9</sup> to see if the last 9 digits match. That will eliminate all but a tiny percentage of random numbers. Or, for an even faster but slightly weaker filter, using 64-bit arithmetic check that the last 20 digits are divisible by 2<sup>20</sup> and not by 10.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy probabilistic solution.

Say your number is `n`, and we want to find `k`: `n = 2^k`. Obviously, `k = log2(n) = log10(n) * log2(10)`. We can estimate `log10(n) ~ len(n)` and find `k' = len(n) * log2(10)` with a small error (say, `|k - k'| <= 5`, I didn't check but this should be enough). Probably you'll need this part in any solutions that can come in mind, it was mentioned in other answers as well.

Now let's check that `n = 2^k` for some known `k`. Select a random prime number `P` with from 2 to `k^2`. If remainders are not equal that `k` is definitely not a match. But what if they are equal? I claim that false positive rate is bounded by `2 log(k)/k`.

Why it is so? Because if `n = 2^k (mod P)` then `P` divides `D = n-2^k`. The number D has length about `k` (because `n` and `2^k` has similar magnitude due to the first part) and thus cannot have more than `k` distinct prime divisors. There are around `k^2 / log(k^2)` primes less than `k^2`, so a probability that you've picked a prime divisor of `D` at random is less than `k / (k^2 / log(k^2)) = 2 log(k) / k`.

In practice, primes up to 10^9 (or even up to `log(n)`) should suffice, but you have to do a bit deeper analysis to prove the probability.

This solution does not require any long arithmetics at all, all calculations could be made in 64-bit integers.

P.S. In order to select a random prime from 1 to T you may use the following logic: select a random number from 1 to T and increment it by one until it is prime. In this case the distribution on primes is not uniform and the former analysis is not completely correct, but it can be adapted to such kind of random as well.

Comment: (Care to add thoughts on (2^p)±1?) ((two typos: `smal` and `arythmetics`))

Comment: @greybeard What do you mean about 2^p ± 1? If you want to check that n = 2^p ± 1, you can do it exactly the same way -- compute the remainder of 2^p ± 1 and check that it matches the remainder of N. Is something else unclear?

Comment: I am too lazy, if at all able to analyse whether remainder modulo a Mersenne prime is above or below average regarding identifying non-powers of two among numbers represented using a base that is not a power of two. Come to think of it, mod 10ⁿ+1 may be more relevant for this question, being similarly easy to compute without multiplication or (explicit) division, and applicable without base conversion to begin with.

Comment: @greybeard I don't get why it is easier to compute large number modulo 10^n+1 than modulo any other number. It is easy to compute n%P in linear (from length of n) time: just proceed digits one by one starting with most significant and iteratively calculate the remainder (given x%P, it is easy to find (x*10+digit)%P). And I can't see any simpler method to compute n%(10^k+1).

Comment: @greybeard More, I grew up on competitive programming competitions and always think of a worst case. If you take remainder over some fixed number (say, 10^18) than it is easy to construct such a testcase that your approach fails.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if its easy to apply, but i would do it in the following way:

1) show the number in binary. now if the number is a power of two, it would look like:

`1000000....`

with only one `1` and the rest are `0`. checking this number would be easy. now the question is how is the number stored. for example, it could have leading zeroes that will harden the search for the 1:

`...000010000....`

if there are only small number of leading zeroes, just search from left to right. if the number of zeroes is unknown, we will have to...

2) binary search for the 1:

2a) cut in the middle.

2b) if both or neither of them are 0 (hopefully you can check if a number is zero in reasonable time), stop and return false. (false = not power of 2)

else continue with the non-zero part.

stop if the non-zero part = 1 and return true.

---

estimation: if the number is n digits (decimal), then its 2^n digits binary.
binary search takes `O(log t)`, and since t = 2^n, log t = n. therefore the algorithm should take `O(n)`.

---

assumptions:

1) you can access the binary view of the number.

2) you can compare a number to zero in a reasonable time.

Comment: But I said that I have this number in decimal, so to have it in binary I should convert my number, which would be no better and even worse than just dividing by 2 while number != 1

Comment: you mean that you don't use the algorithm on standard computer, that already store numbers in binary value? because if you do, maybe you don't have to convert, rather read directly from the computer memory...